# Reset button doesn't work at custom OpenWRT build

Tags: gpio, openwrt

I am compiling a custom OpenWRT firmware for router WL-WN527G4 REV.A (MT7621).

This router has a reset button. This is a physical button on router's back. But this button doesn't work in my compiled firmware. Nothing happening when I press this button.

I have connected router to my PC using UART console and "minicom" app and there is no any output in "minicom" when I am pressing reset button. I have checked output with "logread" util on router and there are nothing here also.

There is a file "/etc/rc.button/reset" with a reset script but I think it not being executed. Also there is no "gpio" directory in "/sys/class".

I think I have missed some kernel modules while compiling OpenWRT. But I don't know what modules I should enable to make this button work.

My ".config" file contains next lines related to gpio:

```
CONFIG_DEFAULT_gpio=y
CONFIG_PACKAGE_kmod-input-gpio-keys=y
CONFIG_PACKAGE_gpio=y
```

How can I get know what modules I should enable to make this button work?

Comment: Do you have kmod-button-hotplug [1], by any chance? Also, you may need to define a hotplug event [2].

[1]: https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt/blob/master/package/kernel/button-hotplug/Makefile
[2]: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/hotplug_lede

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your target dts file.

Example:

```
    keys {
        compatible = "gpio-keys";

        reset {
            label = "reset";
            gpios = <&gpio 18 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
            linux,code = <KEY_RESTART>;
        };
    };
```